No muestra la función
Estoy aprendiendo Python y uso PyCharm como entorno de desarrollo. Estoy iniciando con def para definir una función y aprendiendo varias formas de hacerlo pero tengo el siguiente problema
def resta(m,n):
    return m-n
resta(5, 3)

def resta(a, b):
    return a-b
resta(a=5, b=3)  # 2

Se supone que al ejecutar debe aparecer 2 y no, es como sino leyera mis funciones.

El problema es que no estas imprimiendo el resultado. Prueba con print(resta(5, 3)) en el primero y print(resta(a=5, b=3)) en el otro.

Si estás siguiendo algún tutorial y ves que eso debería imprimir algo por pantalla es porque seguramente están ejecutando el código en un intérprete interactivo (REPL). Fuera de eso, ese código no va a mostrar nada por pantalla (stdin) porque no estás imprimiendo nada como comenta aeportugal, si quieres mírate este ejemplo ejecutable online con varias opciones a ver si te resuelve las dudas: https://godbolt.org/z/KansxMd7M.

Muchas gracias. En efecto, era eso. Qué tonto, pensé que bastaba con definir la resta para imprimir. Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder.
